# ERR Failed to perform any bulk index operations: filebeat to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

While sending data through curl I can send it successfully(from filebeat to aws elasticsearch directly) but when I try to do similar thing with filebeat I got this error:

```
2018/04/11 11:25:50.252835 reader.go:138: DBG  End of file reached: /var/log/Xorg.0.log; Backoff now.
2018/04/11 11:25:50.267537 client.go:112: ERR Failed to perform any bulk index operations: 406 Not Acceptable
2018/04/11 11:25:50.267617 single.go:77: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): 406 Not Acceptable
2018/04/11 11:25:50.267656 single.go:154: INFO send fail
2018/04/11 11:25:50.267682 single.go:161: INFO backoff retry: 1s
2018/04/11 11:25:50.270244 reader.go:138: DBG  End of file reached: /var/log/dpkg.log; Backoff now.
2018/04/11 11:25:50.311799 reader.go:138: DBG  End of file reached: /var/log/bootstrap.log; Backoff now.
2018/04/11 11:25:51.267953 client.go:297: DBG  ES Ping(url=http://x.x.x.x:80, timeout=1m30s)
2018/04/11 11:25:51.886802 client.go:306: DBG  Ping status code: 200
2018/04/11 11:25:51.889365 bulkapi.go:130: DBG  Sending bulk request to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/_bulk
2018/04/11 11:25:52.155389 reader.go:138: DBG  End of file reached: /var/log/apport.log; Backoff now.
```

## My Filebeat.yml is:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - 
      paths: 
        - /var/log/*.log
      enabled: false
output:
    elasticsearch:
      hosts: ["myelasticsearchip"]
      pipeline: test-pipeline
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: 406 not acceptable means the format is not matching, what does the pipeline look like?

Comment: Thanks for response
this is our pipeline look like
{"test-pipeline":{"description":"Test pipeline","processors":[{"lowercase":{"field":"beat.name"}}]}}

Comment: And what does your document look like, please add it to the post not in comment

Comment: Hey @Ashrita how do you manage to send filebeat logs to aws directly?